# I want to add a "+" between every character in a string and a "_" between every space (javascript)

Tags: javascript

For example: "This is code" should return "T+h+i+s_i+s_c+o+d+e"

```
 function addStuff(str) {
    return str.split("").join("_");
 }
```

This returns only "This_is_code"

Need help adding the "+"'s

NON REGEX answers please***

Comment: That code does not return `"This_is_code"`, it returns `"T_h_i_s_ _i_s_ _c_o_d_e"`.

Comment: Your requirement to not use regex is somewhat absurd, since that is the only reasonable way to do global replacements in JavaScript. Here is a solution that does use a regex: `str.split('').join('+').replace(/\+ \+/g, '_')`

Comment: @Paulpro Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
> str = "This is code"
"This is code"
> str.split(' ').map(function(x) {return x.split('').join('+')}).join('_')
"T+h+i+s_i+s_c+o+d+e"
```

Comment: You beat me by a few seconds here. My solution wasn't as elegant anyway :-)

Comment: @JawadSeddar What was yours?

Comment: Basically the same but using a loop instead of the map function call.

Comment: Thanks @NehalJWani appreciate the help!